# How do I make a realistic container without the over head of a vm

Tags: desktop-environments, container

So I want to make a simulated LAN for a locally hosted hacking mc thing. And I want to reward creative thinking. I order to do so I need a container that has systemd, a desktop environment(kde for example), pipewire, Dbus, etc. So you could use waypipe or other stuff for hacking. So desktop kubuntu but in a container.

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu? Please edit your question with specific errors you are having. Include version number of the OS and steps you have taken.

Comment: How much are you paying someone to develop this - i.e. what is the "reward"?

Comment: @OrganicMarble like video game reward as your actions are enolaged

Comment: I'm sure folks are clamoring to be enolaged. Best wishes.